# Layouting in iOS - How can I create a layout like this?

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create an app looks like Twitter's app..

[image]

I wonder how can I do this layout? If I would write in Java/Swing, I use layout managers; create a box or table layout manager and add labels, inputs and other elements to layout manager or I would  use Html, I create a table and add labels, inputs to cells of the table and I would set rectangle background (Number 1 in image) as table's background.

But there is no layout manager or table in iOS like in Java or CSS and I am little confused about what I should do?

I changed View's background to gray and added an ImageView for rectangle background (Number 1 in image) and created inputs and labels on this ImageView but I think there must be easier method to do this?

Comment: it's all hold on  `UITabBarController`(what you see at the bottom). At the top it's a `UINavigationController` and in the middle it's a `UITableView`(grouped style). There is a ton of tutorials around that kind of design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using`UITableView`. TableView should have 2 sections with 3 and 2 rows respectively.

Then you can subclass `UITableViewCell`. For bottom section you need not subclass tableViewCell you can use style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`  and use `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` provided by it.

Others can be  created using prototype cell provided by storyboard.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helps.. I have found this link http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ and learnt how to make UITableViewCell subclasses and customize with XIB...

Answer (score 2):

At the top you have a UINavigationBar.  The whole thing is in a UITabBarViewController that gives you the bar at the bottom.  The view its self is a UITableView set to group sections.  The contents of the cells are pretty straight-forward labels and views.

There are a ton of tutorials on UITableViewController.  I'd start there.  Here is an example: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/